# Neural Network Results Are Not Close To Test Data

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trying to forecast electricity prices for short term with custom neural network in matlab. I have data file which has include 14 input parameters. I used 2012 and 2013, 2 years real data for training and test the model 2014 first 7 month real data. My question is when I compare test data with model outputs it has huge gap. I do not know the results are so far away from test data.

1.This is how I creat the Training and Test datas.

```
            `% Interpolate missing values
            ind = data.ElecPrice==0;
            data.ElecPrice(ind) = interp1(find(~ind), data.ElecPrice(~ind), find(ind));
            % Create training set
            trainInd = data.NumDate < datenum('2014-01-01');
            trainX = X(trainInd,:);
            trainY = data.ElecPrice(trainInd);
            % Create test set and save for later
            testInd = data.NumDate >= datenum('2014-01-01');
            testX = X(testInd,:);
            testY = data.ElecPrice(testInd);
            testDates = dates(testInd);
            save testSet testDates testX testY
            clear X data trainInd testInd term holidays dates ans num text`
```

2. This is my custom neural network model calling code

   ```
           `reTrain = false;
           if reTrain || ~exist('Models\NNModel.mat', 'file')
           net = newfit(trainX', trainY', 20);
           net.performFcn = 'mae';
           net = train(net, trainX', trainY');
           save Models\NNModel.mat net
           else
           load Models\NNModel.mat
           end`
   ```
3. And my last step is predict the prices for 2014 first 7 month
           `forecastPrice = sim(net, testX')';`

4.**My Model propersties are:**

4.1.My Model has 1 input, 2 layers and 1 output. 
    My connections:

```
            `biasConnect: [1; 1]
            inputConnect: [1; 0]
            layerConnect: [0 0; 1 0]
            outputConnect: [0 1]`
```

4.2.Model functions:

```
        `
            adaptFcn: 'adaptwb'
            adaptParam: (none)
            derivFcn: 'defaultderiv'
            divideFcn: 'dividerand'
            divideParam: .trainRatio, .valRatio, .testRatio
            divideMode: 'sample'
            initFcn: 'initlay'
            performFcn: 'mae'
            performParam: .regularization, .normalization
            plotFcns: {'plotperform', plottrainstate, plotfit,
                      plotregression}
            plotParams: {1x4 cell array of 4 params}
            trainFcn: 'traingdm'
            trainParam: .showWindow, .showCommandLine, .show, .epochs,
                        .time, .goal, .min_grad, .max_fail, .lr, .mc`
```

4.3. Model' first layer properties:

```
        `  name: 'Hidden Layer'
                dimensions: 20
               distanceFcn: (none)
             distanceParam: (none)
                 distances: []
                   initFcn: 'initnw'
               netInputFcn: 'netsum'
             netInputParam: (none)
                 positions: [1x20 double]
                     range: [20x2 double]
                      size: 20
               topologyFcn: 'hextop'
               transferFcn: 'tansig'
             transferParam: (none)
                  userdata: (your custom info)`
```

4.4. Model' second layer properties:

```
   name: 'Output Layer'
        dimensions: 1
       distanceFcn: (none)
     distanceParam: (none)
         distances: []
           initFcn: 'initnw'
       netInputFcn: 'netsum'
     netInputParam: (none)
         positions: 0
             range: [1x2 double]
              size: 1
       topologyFcn: 'hextop'
       transferFcn: 'tansig'
     transferParam: (none)
          userdata: (your custom info)
```

I hope you can  help me.

[image: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/28196/data.png]

Comment: Does this question has to do with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353087/matlab-neural-network-constant-value-result . Consider closing the other one if this is the same problem.

Comment: It just looks like your NN is not properly trained.

Comment: Or the network topology isn't properly chosen. A bias input would be helpful for the training. It is necessary for us to have some insight in the training data structure and the chosen topology

Comment: Hi @AnderBiguri it was same problem however I solve the previous problem with constant value. I had different values however it is not even close the test datas.

Comment: Hi @HartmutPfitzinger it is one input (input size is 14) one outpout 2 layer Levenberg-Marquart, 20 hidden layer, weight function is dotdrop, learn function is learngdm, topology function hextop and netInput Function is netsum. I hope those informations are enough. I used "net = init(net)" function the reduce the mape. It is working but not enough for desired levels

Comment: Input size 14, but is there a bias input? 20 hidden layer?! Spelling mistake? 1 or 2 should be enough for the beginning.

Comment: @HartmutPfitzinger I am sorry 20 neurons (spelling mistake). 14 training data. I create struct data with those 14 data.     `weight and bias values:
 
                IW: {2x1 cell} containing 1 input weight matrix
                LW: {2x2 cell} containing 1 layer weight matrix
                 b: {2x1 cell} containing 2 bias vectors`. Maybe I have to have limits for predicted datas.

Comment: Still, 20 neurons are too much to start with, although it depends on the number of input vectors you have for training. Without your matlab program and two or three lines from your training data I can't say anything further.

Comment: Post the piece of code where you train the data please!

Comment: Please edit relevant information into the question, including info in the comments about your network, and some relevant code (not all of it, and please not a link to 3.5MB zipped file via dropbox) . Stack Overflow is a Q&A site - we need a stand-alone and well-defined question for others to learn from. You should not expect Stack Overflow volunteers to work directly on your thesis documents - take some time to present the question well.

Comment: @NeilSlater thank you for your feedback. I revised my question with codes. I hope it is ok with stackoverflow. Hope to someone help me.

Comment: @HartmutPfitzinger I revise question and datas.

Comment: @AnderBiguri thank you for your help. I revised the question

Comment: I don't know this library, but would guess your problem is wrong choice of transfer function on the output layer. I would be more confident of that if the graph was even flatter. However, you probably just want linear in the output layer for this kind of regression problem.

Comment: @NeilSlater I have already try tansig, logsig and purelin functions and none of give me good results. I have even had negative values

Comment: Just throwing this out of the blue; are you sure the data is being splitted correctly (to avoid overfitting issues)?

Comment: @jablesauce I actually found that it is about transfer function. When I change the layer 1-2 transfer functions results accurately changed. However when I change the training functions forexample I used "traingdm" as you see above. When I change it to "trainlm" the results are same. Do you have any idea what is the problem?